# Escape string/keyword in ternary conditional

Tags: php, laravel, escaping, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel as my PHP framework and using Blade as the template engine for my views. I like to keep my code neat so I often use the ternary operator to keep conditionals short.

I've got the following code

```
<h4>{{ $product['instalments'] === 0 ? 'this or that' : 'something else' }}</h4>
```

Problem is this throws an error, I've narrowed it down to the use of "or" in my string as this is used as a keyword within Laravel. I know I can rewrite this using the @if directive but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Does anyone know how I can escape this so it doesn't try and evaluate?

Comment: Is writing it as `'this o'.'r that'` an option?

Comment: Cheers, concatenating strings works but is a little messy, if there's not a cleaner solution I'll probably just use @if. Cheers though!

Answer (score 0):

The suspect is in `$product['instalments'] === 0`

You need to make sure `$product` exists first before trying to get an element from it

Maybe you can change your code to:

```
<h4>{{ empty($product['installments']) ? 'this or that' : 'something else' }}</h4>
```

Comment: The issue is with the string containing "or" as $product['instalments'] returns 0

Comment: No, php won't mess with keywords within quotes. You may write simple code like echo 'this or that'; to try it